# error in disk partitioning during ubuntu server 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, server, partitioning, system-installation

I'm installing ubuntu server on an old 2003 dell computer that has a 2 GHz intel processor, 128 MB RAM and 40 GB HDD. I'm installing from a multiboot usb. Everything goes fine; however when I get to partitioning the hard drive, I get this (I'd post the image, but ask ubuntu doesn't let me yet):

```
[!!] Partition disks
       ??? ???
<Go back> <Continue>
```

Whether I click continue or go back, the screen becomes purple with a white line below and does nothing.

P.s.: The computer has windows xp installed and it run without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The official guide is https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html

For your current purposes you might find this [useful](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2013/02/manual-disk-partition-guide-for-ubuntu-server-edition.html)